# Algebraic simplification problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I must simplify this expression:
>   $$\frac{a^2+ac}{a^2c-c^3}-\frac{a^2-c^2}{a^2c+2ac^2+c}+\frac{2c}{c^2-a^2}-\frac{3}{a+c}$$

I managed to simplify it to:
$$\frac{( a+1)^2-(a+c)^2}{c(a+c)(a+1)^2}$$
However, I am stuck now. Therefore, I would like some help to simplify it further.

Comment: Yes. It is true. Please continue this

Comment: As you are a newcomer on this site, you must say more than the raw question : you must explain what you have attempted and where you are blocked.

Comment: Ok.wait a moment

Comment: I change it to(( a+1)^2-(a+c)^2)/(c(a+c)(a+1)^2)

Comment: Can you continue this

Comment: If the expression you just gave is a simplification of the 5 terms and is exact, use the fact that the numerator has the form $A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B)$ with $A=a+1$ and $B=a+c$.

Comment: Does the denominator of the second term need to have $c^{\color{red}{3}}$ at the end ?

Comment: No. It is so easy. I think it can changes to very simple sentence.  JeanMarie

Comment: I dont think. Donald

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\frac{a(a+c)}{c(a-c)(a+c)}-\frac{(a-c)(a+c)}{ac(a+c)+c(a+c)}+\frac{2c}{(c-a)(a+c)}-\frac{3}{a+c}$$

Comment: this is a nice hint! and the denominators must be $\ne 0$

Comment: I don't know if the OP will appreciate the humor, but I appreciate it. The category "askers who want all without effort" is a plague.

Comment: @Ahmadrezah: is it clear?